# is there a way to autowire an object via constructor in spring boot without passing the values in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

Not able to read the config values from the other class at constructor level.
Tried using @Value annotation but getting null pointer error.
Not able to read the config values from the other class at constructor level. Tried using @Value annotation but getting null pointer error.

Comment: to have a help from our side please provide a simple reproducible example